# Is vxCopyUserDataObject thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, race-condition, openvx

I'm calling `vxCopyUserDataObject` from an independent thread (no graphs in this thread) using a user input.

This function has the following signature:

```
VX_API_ENTRY vx_status VX_API_CALL vxMapUserDataObject  (   
    vx_user_data_object      user_data_object,
    vx_size     offset,
    vx_size     size,
    vx_map_id *     map_id,
    void **     ptr,
    vx_enum     usage,
    vx_enum     mem_type,
    vx_uint32   flags 
)
```

The graph writes on the `user_data_object` at every execution.

Is this thread function safe? Can there be a race condition if the graph is writting at the same time that I call `vxCopyUserDataObject`? If yes, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Based on the documentation, this writes to or reads from `user_data_object`. I don't see any indication that this modifies global state, so by itself, I don't see why it wouldn't be thread-safe. However, are you guarding `user_data_object` from being accessed in multiple threads at once?

Comment: @ThomasJager I am not guarding it. I'm just "feeding" it to a node in the graph. This node will write on it at each execution. I want to read its content from my thread.